# Sinon mocked object doesn't contain original object's functions at top level

Tags: ember.js, mocking, qunit, sinon

So I'm trying to test that this function calls ctrl.set with those specified arguments.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
        $(".poptop").popover({placement: 'top',trigger: 'hover'});

        var ctrl = this.get('controller');
        ctrl.set('capsSet',     false);
        return;
```

My QUnit test looks like this:

```
QUnit.test("Let's blah", function() {

    var controller = App.LoginIndexController.create();
    var mockController = sinon.mock(controller);
    mockController.expects("set").once().callsArgWith(2, 'capsSet', false);
    loginInputFieldView.set("controller", mockController);

    loginInputFieldView.didInsertElement();
    mockController.verify();
});
```

Once `this.get('controller')` is called it returns the mock object that I set in the test. Unfortunately the mock object does not contain the `set()` function at the top level. That set function is found inside `ctrl.object` and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object # has no method 'set'" error.
```

Why is that? Shouldn't the mock object contain the same exact properties/functions as the original object?

Comment: Ah I figured it out. I'm used to testing with Mockito in Java so was assuming it was the same. I shouldn't be setting the controller property to be the mockController. I should be setting it to be the original controller.  The original controller notifies the mockController when a the function is called.  The mockController is more of a spy than a clone.

Comment: In fact, `mock.expects("set")` replaces the original method on the mocked object with an expectation (a spy) rather than declaring a `set` method on `mock` itself. You are correct that in contrast to Mockito and the other Java mocking frameworks, `mock` is *not* a stand-in for the original object but rather an outside helper for declaring expectations. This is most likely a consequence of there being no way to dynamically intercept all functions called on an object.

Comment: As an aside, by using [Sinon's QUnit integration](http://sinonjs.org/qunit/) you can replace `QUnit.test` with `test` and call `this.mock(...)` and `this.spy(...)` in a test method and get auto-verification of mocks and auto-restoration of spies, respectively. Oh, and you should instead post your realization as a proper answer rather than an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using the mocked object like this

```
loginInputFieldView.set("controller", mockController);
```

you should use the original object

```
loginInputFieldView.set("controller", controller);
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time!